# Chrome is printing PDF checkboxes CHECKED even when they are not checked on screen

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have a PDF document that I've got from the UK government for a project I'm working on and against this form I use an FDF file to populate the data and tick various options as required.

This all works perfectly - except that in Chrome, when the data populated PDF is shown on screen everything looks exactly as it should. But when printed, one checkbox in particular, is being shown as checked within print preview and the printed document, even though on screen it is not checked (and nor should it be checked)

The checkbox involved, allows a user to choose option A or option B ... if option A is checked then on screen it shows A is checked, B is not checked ... when printed it shows both A and B being checked

If I use Adobe Acrobat reader to view and print the PDF, it's perfect. The same with Mac Safari. On Windows, Edge and Firefox on screen show both A & B checked, but Internet Explorer works properly and only shows (and prints) option A as being checked

Clearly the browsers are not rendering the PDF correctly, but I can't tell my clients that it's Google's fault

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `I can't tell my clients that it's Google's fault.` Why not? The PDF viewer in Chrome [is not perfect](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=print+component%3AInternals%3EPlugins%3EPDF+&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Stars+ReleaseBlock+Component+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids).

Comment: Furthermore without you sharing the sample pdf in that problem state, how should we analyze the problem?